# Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://xxxxxxx.com/ for apps targeting >= R

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have Capacitor 4 with ionic 6 project and target API is 32.
I am unable to use linkedin APIs after debugging i found this error,

`Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://linkedin.com/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution i had to downgrade capacitor android version to 4.7.2 because 4.7.3 has a bug. Hope this will save someone time!